# javascript : I can not declare variables with var prefix in context of prototype

Tags: javascript, performance

Hi I'm giving my sample code as :

```
function A(){
    var varD = 89
}

A.prototype = {
    varA : 90
    var varC = 91
}
```

I want to use this object A in my 3-4 scripts .All scripts are inter-related and this object A is declared outside window.onload method.
I want to add other variables to object A
I want to access varA , varB, varC in all my scripts and change them when needed.
How can I achieve these functionality.

Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you could use something like the following:

```
A.prototype.varD = 10;
```

And use it with all the objects.

Comment: means i need to declare varB in A.prototype method ?but how to use varC as I can not use var before varC..I dont want to use A.prototype.varD bcoz variables without declaring them as var creates problem in IE

Comment: And how varC with same value will be accessed outside function A.

Comment: I dont get you exactly, what do you want to do?